# HP 4729 is not installing device software over USB

Tags: printer

I am using **HP DESKJET 4729 INK ADVANTAGE PRINTER**. Recently I have changed it's logic board for malfunctioning, after that, installed new catridges , after that the printer can print it's status pages, can make copy;(using front panel); no error or blinking lights, normal startup sound seems like no hardware issues. When I connect the usb cable, the computer shows the machine with normal usb sound,(also gives the option of ejecting the device as it gives when we connect any pen drive etc.) But the problem is when I try to install the latest official driver software for it,(using USB) it says like this : [image]

****I have  tried the following :**

1.**updated to the latest firmware.**

2.**uninstalled the software and installed again.**

3.**Added the printer from "devices and scanners, it adds and recognizes the printer, but it says "DRIVER UNAVILABLE"**

4.**Installed driver from windows update.****

I am almost sure there is not any hardware issue, but how to fix this crappy machine? it is giving me hard time.

Comment: Have you checked if it works with a different computer?

Comment: no I didnt, actually i do not have the scope

Comment: Check what is displayed in Windows device manager. Also check Windows system event log.

Comment: Is there any other alternative which I can try?

Comment: @Robert what should I expect from those?

Comment: @Sayan Understanding what might be the problem? E.g. if the device entry or some log entries use a different printer name then you know that the used logic board was the wrong type.

Comment: @Robert the device manager shows the printer model name which is correct